# Разбор слова по составу

Tags: морфология

Помогите, пожалуйста, как разобрать слово "езда"?
Мне кажется, корень"е", суффикс "зд", окончание "а".

Comment: Корень -езд-, окончание -а.

Answer (score 1):

В этом слове корень "езд" и окончание "а".

Comment: Знаю. Но если Вы, Ярослав, смогли зайти на этот форум, то сможете и перепроверить меня, набрав в поисковике слово "езда", а потом нажав на слово "Словарь"... А в чем Вы видите трудность  разбора?

Answer (score 0):

При образовании слова и его изменении могут происходить различные процессы: чередование, усечение, упрощение и т.д. Видимо, Вас смущает видоизменение корня: ех-а-ть, ед-у, езд-а. Но это не значит. что корень - только общая буква "Е".